# Protected access specifier is in accessible

Tags: c++, algorithm, generics, stack

The following code gives out an compilation error with a message "x is not declared in the scope", even though the child class can access the protected member, what is the reason for this?

```
template<class dt>
class test1
{
protected:
    dt x;
};

template<class dt>
class test2:public test1<dt>
{
    public:
    void SetVals(int xarg)
    {
        x = xarg;
    }

    void GetVals()
    {
        cout<<x<<endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    test2<int> obj;

    obj.SetVals(10);
    obj.GetVals();
    return 0;
}
```